# Azure functions on Premises - Why use a SQL Database configuration for connection?

Tags: sql, database, function, azure, runtime

Do You know what is the purpose of using Database Configuration (Connection),
for Azure functions on Premises (runtime V2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this answer in other forum.

It just acts as a data store for all the data that the solution needs to function. Accounts (usernames, passwords, profiles), subscriptions, functions list, etc. All that information need to be saved in some data store.

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/701